# Data warehouse for ERA-5 data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, weather

I'm new to GIS an this kind of data.

I want to create for my team an easy way to obtain weather data.
We are using https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land?tab=overview dataset.

Requirements:

1. The user should be able to put polygon and receive all points within it. Eg 3 points and all historical data related with those points.
2. Should be fairly fast not as cds.

So **the first solution** I came up with is

1. Convert it to csv format lat, long, time, weather data
2. And load it to database creating from lat, long a Postgis Point -> point, time, weather data

The problem with this solutions is

1. It takes a lot of time to convert it.
2. It takes approximately 7x more disk space.

**The second solution**:

1. I used `raster2pgsql NETCDF:"100_land.nc":tp raster_land > rh_tmp.sql` and load it to postgres.

*I can't figure out how to query this format? Is it possible to eg. provide point/polygon and get all historical weather data for this polygon/point?*

**The third solution** is to create some python library that would operate directly on grib and netcdf.

*In your opinion what is the best solution? How do you do things?*

Comment: I can only partially answer the question : for *solution 2* it's possible to return only those pixels that are located in a polygon (with [**ST_Intersects()**](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersects.html) and [**ST_Clip()**](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html), like [here](https://postgis.net/2014/09/26/tip_count_of_pixel_values/)) or near a point (with [**ST_nearestValue()**](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_NearestValue.html)). I think that it is best to use the second solution, beacause it's simpler than the third and lighter than the first.